# nodemailer not sending with api-gateway-url/dev/submit

Tags: express, aws-api-gateway, nodemailer

I have a problem with my express.js nodemailer since when I use the /submit it works for the localhost but when I use the api gateway url it doesnt work for the localhost and the uploaded website. Btw I use the aws api gateway.

This is my app.js from my express.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname)); // Serve static files

// Nodemailer transporter setup
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: 'my-email',
        clientId: 'number.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        clientSecret: 'number',
        refreshToken: 'number',
        accessToken: 'number',
        expires: 1484314697598
    }
});

app.get('my-api-url/dev/submit', (req, res) => {
    console.log('GET request received at /');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'contact.html'));
});

app.post('my-api-url/dev/submit', (req, res) => {
    console.log('POST request received at /submit');
    let formData = req.body;

    // Format the form data as columnar text
    let emailContent = Object.keys(formData).map(key => {
        return `${key}: ${formData[key]}`;
    }).join('\n');

    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'my-personal-email',
        to: 'my-other-personal-email',
        subject: 'Form Submission',
        text: emailContent
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error sending email:', error);
            res.send('Failed to send email. Please try again later.');
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent:', info.response);
            res.redirect('contact.html?submitted=true');
        }
    });
});

app.use((req, res) => {
    console.log(`Route not found: ${req.url}`);
    res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '404.html'));
});

const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

and this is the code from my style.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    const submitButton = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

    form.addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

        try {
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            const response = await fetch('my-api-url/dev/submit', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                submitButton.value = 'Submitted';
                submitButton.disabled = true;
            } else {
                throw new Error('Error sending form data');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            alert('Error submitting form. Please try again.');
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the code for my aws function

```
/*
Copyright 2017 - 2017 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of the License is located at
    http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0/
or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
*/




const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware')

// declare a new express app
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())

// Enable CORS for all methods
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
  next()
});


/**********************
 * Example get method *
 **********************/

app.get('/submit', function(req, res) {
  // Add your code here
  res.json({success: 'get call succeed!', url: req.url});
});

/****************************
* Example post method *
****************************/

app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
  // Add your code here
  res.json({success: 'post call succeed!', url: req.url, body: req.body})
});

app.post('/submit/*', function(req, res) {
  // Add your code here
  res.json({success: 'post call succeed!', url: req.url, body: req.body})
});

/****************************
* Example put method *
****************************/

app.put('/submit', function(req, res) {
  // Add your code here
  res.json({success: 'put call succeed!', url: req.url, body: req.body})
});

app.put('/submit/*', function(req, res) {
  // Add your code here
  res.json({success: 'put call succeed!', url: req.url, body: req.body})
});

/****************************
* Example delete method *
****************************/

app.delete('/submit', function(req, res) {
  // Add your code here
  res.json({success: 'delete call succeed!', url: req.url});
});

app.delete('/submit/*', function(req, res) {
  // Add your code here
  res.json({success: 'delete call succeed!', url: req.url});
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("App started")
});

// Export the app object. When executing the application local this does nothing. However,
// to port it to AWS Lambda we will create a wrapper around that will load the app from
// this file
module.exports = app
```

I havent tried anything yet for the code. I expect the code to send an email to my other email . It works with the /submit with localhost but it doesnt work when I use the api-gateway-url/dev/submit. And it doesnt show any errors.